# Unsupported C.P.U for windows 10

Tags: cpu, compatibility, windows-10-upgrade

I have Intel i5-4200u . Earlier the windows get application showed that my laptop can run windows 10. But it performed another check on 13-6-15 and it now shows that my c.p.u is not supported.Is this c.p.u supported or is there some other problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Windows 10 would definitely work with this processor.

However, if it is saying it is not supported, I would recommend speaking to Microsoft, perhaps they may have more of an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft, Windows 10 requires a 1 GHz or faster CPU.

Apart from this the CPU should support PAE (Physical Address Extension), NX (No-eXecute) and SSE2.

The Intel i5 4200U supports all these instructions and you can validate it by running CPU-Z. Only thing is that Intel's way of saying its CPU supports PAE and NX is to look for the EM64T and VT-x/VT-d instruction respectively is present or not in the set of intrusions listed by CPU-Z.

I am posting my i5 4200U's CPU-Z screenshot for your convenience.

[image]

So you are good to try Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some features are disabled in BIOS and that is why the CPU gets listed as unsupported. Check CPU-related settings in BIOS and enable them.

Comment: Can you specify CPU-related settings? I couldn't find anything that may effect this.

Comment: Names vary a lot from one BIOS configuration to another. Usually, in many BIOSes the main menu is called CPU features.